# How many actual files were you able to store in a CentOS folder?

Tags: linux, filesystems, centos, ext4, ext3

I found many questions about the `total files` limitations of the CentOS file-system, but I was curios in actual real-world situation, how many files people were able to store in one single CentOS folder.

I have a site with around 5 million images on one directory and I notice that images tend to disappear even though `df -ih` command says innode is around 29%

Answer (score 1):

CentOS is a Linux distribution, not a filesystem.

The limitations you refer to are, indeed, filesystem limitations. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40368/maximum-number-of-inodes-in-a-directory) Stack Overflow thread and [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/396768/ext4-file-system-max-inode-limit-can-anyone-please-explain) Server Fault thread have some good pointers to you.

Comment: It's a file system decision. For some really insane limits see: http://www.freebsd.org/doc/faq/book.html#idp61899696